# How to prevent pmax/pmin from taking non-numerical values into consideration?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using `pmax` and `pmin` to extract the max and min values from each row. I have some values that are statistically not significant and these values are surrounded by <>. For some reason, `pmax` and `pmin` still take into consideration these values and then I cannot calculate the difference between values that are significant. Below is an example:

| ID | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | Var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | !5! | NA | 10 |
| B | 20 | NA | NA | 3 |
| C | !20! | 10 | NA | NA |
| D | NA | NA | 30 | NA |
| E | !10! | NA | NA | NA |

I want the !xx! values not included when I do the following:

```
DF1 = data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E"), 
                 Var1=c("1","20","!20!","NA","!10!"), 
                 Var2=c("!5!","NA","10","NA","NA"), 
                 Var3=c("NA","NA","NA","30","NA"), 
                 Var4=c("10","NA","NA","NA","NA"),
                 Var5=c("NA","!50!","20","NA","NA"))
```

```
DF1$max <- pmax(DF1$Var1,DF1$Var2,DF1$Var3,DF1$Var4,na.rm = TRUE)
DF1$min <- pmin(DF1$Var1,DF1$Var2,DF1$Var3,DF1$Var4,na.rm = TRUE)
```

This leads to me getting the following:

[image]

When the following is what I want:
[image]

How do I prevent the !xx! values from being taken up by `pmax` and `pmin`? I appreciate any help!

Comment: Your data has `"NA"` as if it represent R's `NA` (null) value, but it is a literal string. Perhaps your fake data is not really representative of something real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `"NA"` is really `NA` (not a string literal):

```r
DF1[-1] <- lapply(DF1[-1], function(z) replace(z, z=="NA", NA))
```

we can do this:

```r
do.call(pmax, c(lapply(DF1[-1], function(z) replace(z, grepl("!", z), NA)), list(na.rm = TRUE)))
# [1] "10" "20" "20" "30" NA  
### and converting to numbers
do.call(pmax, c(lapply(DF1[-1], function(z) suppressWarnings(as.numeric(replace(z, grepl("!", z), NA)))), list(na.rm = TRUE)))
# [1] 10 20 20 30 NA
```

results stored with:

```r
nums <- lapply(DF1[-1], function(z) suppressWarnings(as.numeric(replace(z, grepl("!", z), NA))))
DF1$min <- do.call(pmin, c(nums, na.rm = TRUE))
DF1$max <- do.call(pmax, c(nums, na.rm = TRUE))
DF1
#   ID Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 min max
# 1  A    1  !5!   NA   10   NA   1  10
# 2  B   20   NA   NA   NA !50!  20  20
# 3  C !20!   10   NA   NA   20  10  20
# 4  D   NA   NA   30   NA   NA  30  30
# 5  E !10!   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA
```

Note that we also need to add `na.rm=FALSE`.

Or, alternatively, we can use `readr::parse_number` like so:

```r
nums <- lapply(DF1[-1], function(z) readr::parse_number(replace(z, grepl("!", z), NA)))
### ... as above
```

Comment: It throws a lot of warnings, but you could also barge through with `as.numeric` as the function too - `do.call(pmax, c(lapply(DF1[-1], as.numeric), na.rm=TRUE))` - this would ensure that the maximum numeric value is taken instead of the maximum character value that I think this code gives.

Comment: @thelatemail that method is definitely more resilient to non-number strings that don't contain `"!"`, and that path can be a double-edged sword, hiding unrecognized changes in the data (I tend to assume code will eventually be used _unsupervised_).

Comment: I do think you still need an `as.numeric` in there somewhere even if more checking code is added, as this code will say `"3"` is greater than `"20"` because the original values like `"!5!"` mean each column is character to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`.

```r
library(dplyr)

suppressWarnings( 
DF1 %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Var"), ~as.numeric(.x), .names = "{col}_num")) %>% 
  mutate(max = do.call(pmax, c(subset(., select = Var1_num:Var5_num), na.rm = TRUE)),
         min = do.call(pmin, c(subset(., select = Var1_num:Var5_num), na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  select(-contains("num"))
)
#>   ID Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 max min
#> 1  A    1  !5!   NA   10   NA  10   1
#> 2  B   20   NA   NA   NA !50!  20  20
#> 3  C !20!   10   NA   NA   20  20  10
#> 4  D   NA   NA   30   NA   NA  30  30
#> 5  E !10!   NA   NA   NA   NA  NA  NA
```